# PhoneGap/Cordova: Prevent horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, cordova, scroll

I have an app built on Cordova and on some of my pages I am able to scroll horizontally out of my content into white space.

This is weird as I have nothing there that extends beyond my `#wrapper`, which is set to `width: 100%`.

So I was wondering if there was a way I could disable horizontal scrolling in the app altogether?

UPDATE:

Code on page as requested:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #b7b8b9;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

iframe{
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 50px;*/


   }

#header{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}


<body>
         <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="headerback"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="headerrefresh"><script>var pathname = window.location.pathname;</script><script>document.write('<a href="'+pathname+'">Refresh</a>')</script></div>
            <div class="headertitle"><h2>Get the Look</h2></div>

        </div><!--HEADER-->
    <iframe src="http://www.mbff.com.au/getthelook"></iframe>
    </div>
    </body>
```

[image: This is what happens on horizontal scroll]

Comment: Is scrolling out of content bounce effect?

Comment: @nhahtdh no, it behaves as though a div is extending out side of the wrapper - its just scrolls into white space slightly

Comment: I cannot seems to reproduce the problem on the device. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for checking! Have adde screen shot above. Note: when the page first loads it appears fine but when you scroll to the right this is what occurs

Comment: The code you provided is probably missing something - I can't reproduce the error. I think you can try to figure out the problem by inspecting the elements in the desktop browser (after scaling the window to approximately the size of the phone).

Comment: Yeah I've tried. I cant find anything! Do you know a way to just turn off the horizontal scroll?

Comment: No. I don't think there is anyway, since the scroll is inside the web view and the property is made readonly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to debug your page in Chrome (webkit) with the exact dimensions of your device. This solves most rendering issues for me.

I do not know the specific issue here, but it looks like one of your elements is flowing outside of the wrapper. You could for example try this in your `css`:

```
div.wrapper { overflow: hidden; width: inherit; }
```

Although it might be a better idea to find out why your page is expanding horizontally?

Comment: Yes thanks Justus. It was an incorrect body width on my iphone specific CSS

Comment: Confirmed this is correct fix with Cordova 6.3.1, running on Android 6 and 7

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the solution to this problem for a long time.
Finally I solved it in the following way.
I set style for `body`and `html` tags:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

After that I've added `div` to `body` and set the style for it:

```
overflow-y: auto;
height: 100%;
```

So, I have got fixed body, which contains div with vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Phone Gap disable only horizontal scrolling in Android.

// Add this code in your Phone Gap  Main Activity.Initially Declare the variable 

private float m_downX;

//Then add this code after loadUrl

this.appView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                // save the x
                m_downX = event.getX();
            }
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                // set x so that it doesn't move
                event.setLocation(m_downX, event.getY());
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following code to your .html file:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: This has prevented even the vertical scrolling.

Comment: how to remove this lsitener after that i tried removeeventlistener but still its is not scrolling

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, I thought the answer which makes use of the official method of doing such a thing via the `preference` tag should be added:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Supported by Android and iOS according the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/).

> Default: false
>
> Set to true if you don't want the interface to display any feedback when users scroll past the beginning or end of content. On iOS, overscroll gestures cause content to bounce back to its original position. on Android, they produce a more subtle glowing effect along the top or bottom edge of the content.

Comment: Note: in the technical sense, this is correct, but some people may experience very small overscrolling (in my case it was a single pixel), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31320257/2374365) worked with this

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was broken styling like below

```
<body>
  <div style="margin-left:5%; width:100%">Content</div>
</body>
```

which cause div to became horizontally bigger than body. I could see scroll when app run in browser. Set width to 90% (as it was initially intended) fixed the problem.

Generally, as it already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326379/2534191), enough to find element with wrong style which makes your page expanding horizontally and fix it.

BTW *DisallowOverscroll* was not helpful in above case.